# IOS 13 Automation Asking To Run

Tags: ios, shortcut

I have created a simple IOS Automation and every time it tries to run, it shows up as a notification asking me if I want it to run. Is there a way to get it to run without prompting me? Automations don’t seem that automated if it requires my input.

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: How is this not a programming question? IOS automations allow the user to program shortcuts. It may not be a programming language such as swift or C++ but it is programming.

Comment: I created an app and I want automations and shortcuts to work with my app correctly and seamlessly. How is this not being a developer?

Comment: Analyzing functionality from the user perspective is a part of being a developer. Btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, for now it's not possible to run automation without authenticate on the phone first. There's some discussion [here](https://appletoolbox.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-shortcuts-automations-in-ios-13-1/) that might interest you.